# Are there Thread interruption Event listeners

Tags: java, multithreading

I was wondering if there are EventListeners for when the interrupted flag on a Thread gets changed via the `.interrupt()` method? The current problem is that I have a run method without a loop, but if an abort button is pushed, I want to stop the execution. If such things don't exist, the question becomes, how can I put it in now? Do I have to design the application from the ground up to support such features? My goal is to have the same functionality as the deprecated `stop()` method without having the downside. My current situtation is the following:

```
public class DoTask implements Runnable {
  public void run(){
    /* a long running task without a loop like loading something with a 
       simple load method.
    */
  }
}
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    ExecutorService executor=Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    JButton button = new JButton("Stop");
    button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        /* stop the executor (or Thread) somehow */
      }
    });
    executor.submit(new DoTask());
    /* all methods from the executor don't stop the Runnable 
       immediately without their knowledge. They don't stop it.
    */
  }
}
```

Best regards pizzadox9999

Comment: Not as a typical add*Listener method, but there are plenty of ways to do this:  synchronized and the wait/notify/notifyAll methods of Object;  the await/signal methods of Lock;  the awaitTermination method of ExecutorService;  Semaphore/CountDownLatch/CyclicBarrier/Phaser;  if using Swing, the addPropertyChangeListener method of SwingWorker;  and if you’re using JavaFX, you can listen to the running or state properties of Worker implementations.

Comment: By the way, you need to add code to handle graceful shutdown of your executer service. See boilerplate in the Javadoc.

Comment: This Question could be improved by specifying the nature of your "long running task without a loop". Example code would help.

Comment: I don't think so. But In there I load something with a load method. Now to avoid rewriting anything so that I can shut it down properly in the load method I would like to figure out other ways, because if the user hits stop I don't care any more about the state of that Class.

Comment: The cancel method of Future will only work if the DoTask.run method checks for an interrupt with reasonable frequency.

Answer (score -1):

This may help. You may be able to use the button to give the interrupt command if I am reading your question correctly. It should only require you to place the command in the buttons action listener execution.

[https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-a-thread-can-interrupt-another-thread-in-java#:~:text=The%20%E2%80%98interrupt%E2%80%99%20function%20can%20be%20used%20in%20Java,once%20it%20is%20interrupted%20%E2%88%92%20Example%20Live%20Demo](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-a-thread-can-interrupt-another-thread-in-java#:%7E:text=The%20%E2%80%98interrupt%E2%80%99%20function%20can%20be%20used%20in%20Java,once%20it%20is%20interrupted%20%E2%88%92%20Example%20Live%20Demo)

Comment: Answers consisting mainly of a link are discouraged, since the link may change or go stale in the future, which would make the answer useless to future readers.  Your answer can be improved by adding your own explanation of how to make use of the recommendations in that link.